# Shifting from XNA/C# to C++?

Tags: xna, c++

For a while now, I've been working with XNA for game design and development (although only for personal use ATM.) Overall, I'm a major fan of XNA itself, and it's overall "feel." However, due to the fact that:

1. XNA seems to have a lack of support (no Metro support, no updates since 2010, etc.)
2. I plan to try and get a job in the game development industry, and due to C++'s dominance, being more familiar with it would be very useful
3. XNA only supports Windows (non-Metro) and Xbox 360, while I am interested in Mac and (to a lesser extent) Linux support.

I've been trying to shift over to C++ as my main language. However, I do not want to focus on learning raw DirectX/C++ at this time, so I've been looking for a higher level C++ API (something about the same level as XNA, although something a bit more low-level would be fine) with a feel similar  to XNA. So, for someone switching from C#/XNA to C++, what would my best choice(s) be for API's similar to XNA, although unmanaged and running on C++?

Comment: DONT EVER use DirectX with C++... Use OpenGL ;)

Answer (score 13):

First of all, if you want to stick with C#/XNA, and still support Mac/Linux, you could consider [FNA](https://fna-xna.github.io/) or [MonoGame](https://web.archive.org/web/20180116103954/http://monogame.codeplex.com:80/).

If you want to enjoy some of XNA's nice helper classes (eg: `SpriteBatch`, `SpriteFont`), while moving over to DirectX/C++, you could try the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) or [DirectX12 Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12). And don't forget that much of the niceness of XNA is in its content pipeline - so [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) might help. It's made by some of the same folks who made XNA, so you know it's good ([blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151001035937/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2012/06/18/directx-tool-kit-is-now-on-codeplex.aspx)).

You could consider trying [Unity](https://unity.com/) - which uses C#, supports Mac and Linux and a bunch of other platforms, and is used in "The Industry".

If you'd like Metro support, want to learn DirectX, but don't want to leave the comfort of C#, you could check out [SharpDX](https://github.com/sharpdx/sharpdx).

Finally, you could look at [Cocos2d-X](https://cocos2d-x.org/), which seems to be quite popular and is probably the closest cross-platform C++ library to XNA that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I want to mention SFML. Everybody using C++ should at least take a look at it as SFML is completely object oriented whereas SDL basically is C.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, these libraries are interesting for solving your migration especially if you want to program in C++:

- SDL, [Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/), very easy, with a good "feeling" and cross-platform;
- [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/), like SDL and well-supported and updated too.